# Entity with Winforms / bindingsource - can't save user input from controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

I have a winforms program I am migrating to entity (EF5).  The edit works okay.  The add does not.  The basic workflow is user can either add or edit an object.  There is a list of comboboxes, text boxes, etc on screen for the user to input.

I have the entity bound to a binding source.  I have the textbox bound to the bindingsource.

Add functionality looks like this.

```
    If (mViewAddEdit = ViewAddEditEnum.Add) Then

        Dim ps As New RADS.PHANTOM_SESSION
        Me.bsPhantom.DataSource = db.PHANTOM_SESSION.Add(ps)
        Me.EdtMuscleWater.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.bsPhantom, "MUSCLE_OR_WATER", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)) ' etc  
    End If
```

So that seems okay, but when user clicks ok button (to save).

```
      drvPhantom = TryCast(Me.bsPhantom.Current, RADS.PHANTOM_SESSION)
' examining the object shows nothing bound.
        If mViewAddEdit = ViewAddEditEnum.Add Then 

                db.PHANTOM_SESSION.Add(drvPhantom)
                db.SaveChanges()
        End If
```

Comment: *"So that seems okay, but when user clicks ok button (to save)"* is not a sentence.  You haven't actually told us what the problem is that we're trying to solve.  That said, why are you calling `Add` twice?

Comment: @jmcilhinney the issue is that the data from the control is not being pushed to the model.  I am casting it (bindingsource.Current) to PHANTOM_SESSION object but the object hold no data.

Comment: Try calling the form's `Validate` method at the start of the second code snippet.  You are telling the `Binding` to update on validation so make sure that that validation has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arose from the form blocking validation.

Me.AutoValidate was set to disable.  So this blocked the binding source from updating even with a call to Me.Validate()

Also since I found it so hard.  This is how to Add or Edit - controls bound to binding source using Entity EF5.

```
  If (mViewAddEdit = ViewAddEditEnum.Add) Then
        Me.bsPhantom.DataSource = New PHANTOM_SESSION
        SetPhantomDataBindings()

    Else
        Dim query = From ps In db.PHANTOM_SESSION Where (ps.PHNTM_SESSION_NO = CDbl(mPhntmSessionNum))
        bsPhantom.DataSource = query.ToList() ' resize occurs here
        SetPhantomDataBindings()
    ...
    End If
```

The other thing is if you are programmatically writing to the text box,  ie textbox1.text = "foo" you must also update the underlying object.

```
CType(Me.bsPhantomBlock.Current, RADS.PHANTOM_BLOCK).OTHER_CORRECTION = CDec(val)
```

Here we are casting the current object of the binding source to its type (PHANTOM_BLOCK) then setting the field "OTHER_CORRECTION" to val.

Updating the binding source does not work as it causes all inputted user data to be thrown away.  For example there are 5 text boxes (a,b,c,d,e). user enters 1,2,3,4,5 into those.  The 5th is handled by bindingsource Write:  textbox1.DataBindings(0).WriteValue  - this will update the 5th field (e),but causes a,b,c,d to be blank as the are reverting to stored value.  This is my experience anyway.